# RecyclerView only showing first product from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a small android app but i can't get this activity work.

This is the Dashboard activity where i expect to see all products but it shows only the first one, the section where they should be shown gets bigger but the other object are not present, anywhere i press on this area the activity related to the first product is started.

```
public class DashBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityDashBoardBinding binding;
    private ProductsAdapter productsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityDashBoardBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        setSupportActionBar(binding.myToolbar);
        productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(this);
        binding.productRecycler.setAdapter(productsAdapter);
        binding.productRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        getProducts();

        binding.cart.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(DashBoardActivity.this, CartActivity.class));
        });
    }

    private void getProducts(){
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("products")
                .whereEqualTo("show", true)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> dsList = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for(DocumentSnapshot ds:dsList){
                        ProductModel productModel = ds.toObject(ProductModel.class);
                        productsAdapter.addProduct(productModel);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

```
public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private List<ProductModel> productModelList;

    public ProductsAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        productModelList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
    }

    public void addProduct(ProductModel productModel){
        productModelList.add(productModel);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProductModel productModel = productModelList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(productModel.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(productModel.getDescription());
        holder.price.setText(productModel.getPrice());

        Glide.with(context).load(productModel.getImage())
                .into(holder.img);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("model", productModel);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productModelList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView title, description, price;
        private ImageView img;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?